# Plot a piecewise function in 3D

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am new to python and trying to 3d plot a piecewise function. I am trying to 3d plot the 'mainformula' function below on the z-axis as it varies with x and y ranging from 0 to 10, and constant = 1. But I can't quite seem to figure out the plotting method here.

```
from sympy import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def mainformula(x,y,constant):
    return Piecewise((subformula1(x,y,constant), y >= 0 and y < 3),(subformula2(x,y,constant),y>=3 and y <= 10))

def subformula1(x,y,constant):
    return x + y + constant

def subformula2(x,y,constant):       
    return x - y - constant

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0, 10, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.25)
constant = 1
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = mainformula(X,Y,constant)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

The error I get when I run that code is: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on arrays so it's never going to work to use `array > 3` in a boolean context (for example with `and`) this will always give you the error you received. But you can always define your conditions as boolean masks and operate your formula on the appropriate elements:

```
def mainformula(x,y,constant):
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    # Condition 1 indexes all elements where subformula 1 is valid
    condition1 = np.logical_and(y >= 0, y < 3)
    # condition1 = (y >= 0) & (y < 3) # is another way of writing it
    z[condition1] = x[condition1] + y[condition1] + constant
    # now do it in the range where subformula 2 is valid
    condition2 = np.logical_and(y >= 3, y <= 10)
    # condition1 = (y >= 3) & (y <= 10) # is another way of writing it
    z[condition2] = x[condition2] - y[condition2] - constant

    return z
```

This doesn't use `sympy.Piecewise` but works alright when only trying to plot. If you want seperate functions instead of doing it all in the main formula you need to change it a bit:

```
z[condition1] = subformula1(x[condition1], y[condition1], constant)
```

and similar for `condition2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is along the lines of what I'm looking to do. Can I add a level of complexity to this? 

Is there a way that "condition1 = np.logical_and(y >= 0, y < 3)" can be changed to have another condition within it:

    condition1 = np.logical_and(y >= 0, y < 3) and np.logical_and(subformula1(x,y,constant) >=0)

Comment: of course, you can also use `&` instead of `np.logical_and` and formulate it as `condition1 = (y >= 0) & (y < 3) & (subformula1(x,y,constant) >=0)` but this will exclude setting some elements in your final `z`. For example what happens if `0 < y < 3` but `subformula1(x,y,c) < 0` ... these elements would be `0` because you don't overwrite them.

Comment: Thanks so much, that does the trick. One last thing. Is there such a thing as np.logical (without the and so I don't have to provide 2 arguments)? So I want something like this:

np.logical_and(y >= 0, y < 3) to np.logical(y < 3) ?

Comment: just use `condition1 = y < 3` if you only have one condition. And don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it solved your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to make logic assertions into arrays that do not have a direct one. It's difficult for Python to assert what this is:

```
    y >= 0 and y < 3
```

So you'll have to change somewhat your code into something it can understand:

```
    def mainformula(x,y,constant):
        y2 = y[y>=0]
        y2 = y2[y2<3]
        y3 = y[y>=3]
        y3 = y2[y2<=10]
        return Piecewise((subformula1(x,y,constant), y2),(subformula2(x,y,constant),y3))
```

The problem is Piecewise function also does not seem to accept some arrays into one of the arguments you have. You'll have to rethink your problem, perhaps by building a loop for the Piecewise function in order to be launched at every element.