# How can I draw a contour for a piecewise function with pyplot.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

My function is `z = (x - 1) **10 + 5*(x - 1)**5*(y - 1)**5 + (y - 1)**10`. However, the contour can't show clear about negative value because of large positive value.

So I just need to show positive value by logarithm (`np.log(1 + 0)` if `z < 0`), but keep negative as origin.

How can I do this with pyplot.imshow?

This code doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def z(x, y):
    z0 = (x - 1) **10 + 5*(x - 1)**5*(y - 1)**5 + (y - 1)**10
    # ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
    return z0 if z0 < 0 else np.log(1 + z0)

def main():
    x, y = np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 300), np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 300)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.imshow(z(X, Y), origin='lower', extent = [0, 3, 0, 3], cmap=plt.cm.hsv)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037658/plot-a-piecewise-function-in-3d but I don't think my case can be solved by numpy's condition.

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Are there any solution to fix the error I marked in the code `# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line of code:

```
return z0 if z0 < 0 else np.log(1 + z0)
```

This line raises a ValueError because you are comparing an array with a scalar. When using NumPy arrays, I would suggest using slicers:

```
def z(x, y):
    z0 = (x - 1) **10 + 5*(x - 1)**5*(y - 1)**5 + (y - 1)**10
    z0[z0 >= 0] = np.log(1 + z0[z0 >= 0])
    return z0
```

The slicers allow you to change just the elements you want from an array.